# Bot Composer - QNA Intent Recognized

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I am trying to utilize the QNA Intent Recognized within Bot Composer, but use a QNA that is already established in QNA Maker.  How to I get the QNA Intent to point to that QNA (seems like you are forced to re-import).

Comment: so your QnA Intent Recognized trigger isn't getting added? We had a similar [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/7523) reported a few weeks back and the fix should be out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using V2.1.2, You may connect directly to your QnA service by:

Access external resources > Connect to QnA Knowledgebase

Then provide KnowledgeBaseID, Endpoint Key and Hostname.

[image]